# don't understand the reason of NullPointerException in my case. Selenium Webdriver + Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have test:

```
 @Test
 public void postStatusTest() {
 loginPage.logInFacebook("my-email", "my-password");
 facebookMainPage.checkNotifications();
 facebookMainPage.postStatus("Test");
 }
```

where:

```
  public FacebookMainPage checkNotifications(){
  if (driver.findElements(notificationsButton).size() > 0) driver.findElement(notificationButton).click();
  return new FacebookMainPage(driver);
  }
```

and:

```
 public FacebookMainPage postStatus(String statusText){
 driver.findElement(textField).click();
 driver.findElement(textField).sendKeys(statusText);
 driver.findElement(postButton).click();
 return new FacebookMainPage(driver);
 }
```

can you, please, explain why in my case both methods `checkNotifications` and `postStatus` return `NullPointerException`? I've read theory, but I hardly understand what in my case can be wrong.

Comment: Scrapping [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the ToS. Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: ok. but what is the reason of NullPointerException in my case? I just want to know so I don't make this mistake in future.